# CI/CD Gitlab deployment heroku - Add dep in docker run image dpl

Tags: docker, heroku, deployment, gitlab-ci

I'm having trouble deploying an application, using Ci/CD gitlab with heroku. I use a docker dpl image, and now I need to add a new dependency.

.gitlab-ci.yml

Currently use: (works)

```
docker run xpp/dpl dpl --provider=heroku --app=myApp --api-key=$HEROKU_KEY
```

I need to add the faraday dep:

```
docker run xpp/dpl /bin/sh -c "gem install faraday -v 1.10.0" dpl --provider=heroku --app=myApp --api-key=$HEROKU_KEY
```

The faraday dependency is successfully installed, but the process is terminated. It doesn't install the heroku dpl, and it doesn't deploy.

Any ideas on how I can resolve this, how can I install and continue the deployment process?

[image]

OBS: I can't edit the xpp/dpl image to add the dependency in the Dockerfile.

Comment: What is the `xpp/dpl` image; it's not on Docker Hub?  The first command line you show suggests it's just a deployment tool, so is there a separate image that includes your application?

Comment: Yes, the xpp/dpl image is on the docker hub. But I couldn't edit her dockerfile :(
This command line calls this image, and then uses it.

Comment: Any tips on how to solve this?